# Not able to reset values in redux form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-form

my dropdown is using redux form, field.

```
<Field name="Name" 
 component={renderSelect} 
 label="" 
 disabled options={options} 
 returnValue={"id"} 
 displayText={"name"} 
/>
```

so this is my dropdown.. I am not able to reset its value when i click clear button

Comment: Anywhere you want. Inline, in its own file, in the function body or render method. Anywhere. This really isn't enough information to give a helpful answer...

Comment: could you please provide me any link for reference, I didnt find anything relevant

Comment: No I can't. I have no idea what you're trying to accomplish. Your question needs more details. Give more context. What is `Field`? Is this a class or functional component? What have you tried and where did it fail?

Comment: <Field  options={}  /> this is a dropdown, which shows array...so options={arrayName}
I need to define this array somewhere ... I defined it in this.state in constructor as  this.state = {
      arrayName: ["1:00", "2:00", "3:00"],
    };
but it aint showing

Comment: Add it to the question please.

Comment: added, I am actually using redux form Field